# phpdoc use multiple directory in parsing

Tags: phpdoc

I want to parse two or more folders with phpdoc. Parsing one folder works fine.

In the documentation, I can see this:

> -d|–directory[=”...”]
>
> Provide a comma-separated list of source folders to parse.

But I can't get it to work using these variations:

> phpdoc.bat -d[application\controllers\mnm,application\libraries] -t phpdoc
>
> phpdoc.bat -d [application\controllers\mnm,application\libraries] -t phpdoc
>
> phpdoc.bat -directory[application\controllers\mnm,application\libraries] -t phpdoc
>
> phpdoc.bat -directory["application\controllers\mnm","application\libraries"] -t phpdoc
>
> phpdoc.bat -directory[="application\controllers\mnm","application\libraries"] -t phpdoc
>
> phpdoc.bat -directory [="application\controllers\mnm","application\libraries"] -t phpdoc
>
> phpdoc.bat -d [="application\controllers\mnm","application\libraries"] -t phpdoc

The error message I receive is

> **[Exception]**
> **No parsable files were found, did you specify any using the -f or -d parameter?**

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path?

Answer (score 7):

This is a solution!

phpdoc.bat -d "application\controllers\mnm","application\libraries" -t phpdoc